# Trigonometry on Obj-C

Tags: ios, trigonometry

I'm trying to use trigonometry to find distances and a-like..

Currently though, I believe my formula to be correct but I get an incorrect degrees when using sin,cos,tan with a particular degree

```
double hypotenuse = [distanceOnTimeScale.text doubleValue];

double fita = 90 - probeAngle;

double sinFita = sin(fita);

double hypCheck = (opposite / sinFita);

double secondLeg = hypotenuse - hypCheck;

double adjacent = (opposite / tan(fita));

NSLog(@"Opposite: %.1f", opposite);
NSLog(@"Fita: %.1f", fita);
NSLog(@"Hypotenuse: %.1f", hypotenuse);
NSLog(@"Hyp Check: %.1f", hypCheck);
NSLog(@"FITA: %f", sinFita);
```

outputs

```
2014-04-18 16:35:51.988 ---[7316:60b] Opposite: 10.0
2014-04-18 16:35:51.991 ---[7316:60b] Fita: 45.0
2014-04-18 16:35:51.992 ---[7316:60b] Hypotenuse: 0.0
2014-04-18 16:35:51.993 ---[7316:60b] Hyp Check: 12.4
2014-04-18 16:35:51.994 ---[7316:60b] FITA: 0.806075
```

As you can see Fita is 45º

so, `sinFita` should equal `0.707106781186547` and it does not, why am I getting this issue?

Comment: You are mixing gedrees and radiants.

Comment: Or, to put it more clearly, you're using degrees when you should be using radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do

```
double sinFita = sin(fita * M_PI / 180);
```

to convert degrees to radians. Which is the conversion factor from degrees to radians.

Comment: No, `M_PI_2` is `pi/2`, not `pi/180`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wasn't aware that radians would be the dominant values used.

Comment: @DanielWatson - Radians are the norm for mathematics and have been used for almost all trig functions since FORTRAN.

Answer (score 5):

The C math functions (e.g. [`sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin)) expect their arguments to be in radians, not degrees.